# Dropdown broken in modal on 0.11

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm facing this problem. I'm migrating from 0.10 to 0.11 of bootstrap ui and the dropdowns inside modals stopped working at all. I don't know if it is a layout problem but I can't figure out how to make them work.

Here it is the demo http://jsbin.com/fidipeho/1/edit?html,js,output

I checked the breaking changes of 0.11 and I didn't find anything that could explain this strange behavior.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as per Mathew, the angular.js script needs to be included for starters, but as far as why the drop down inside the modal is not working, that is a different issue.

The HTML for the dropdown should be like this:

```
<div class="btn-group" dropdown is-open="dropdown.isopen">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" data-ng-disabled="disabled">
  Action <span class="caret"></span>
 </button>
 <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

the div that holds the dropdown (btn-group) needs to include 'dropdown' and 'is-open="whatever variable you want"' and the button within the div needs to have data-ng-disabled="disabled".

Answer (score 0):

Looks like angular is not being included, try changing your include to this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.10/angular.js"></script>
```

With that I was able to get the application working.